# You don't... - I don't?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> A: You don't have to worry about that.
>
> B: **I don't?**
>
> A: No, you don't.

Is "I don't?" the only correct option? What about "Don't I?" or "Shouldn't I?"

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of "correct" responses.

You could ask a question for clarification "Don't I?".  Or ask for clarification with a question formed by intonation: "I don't?". You could query the speaker with "Why not?" or contradict them "I do worry". Asking "shouldn't I?" is another possible and correct response.

Of course, there are many possible incorrect responses. "No, you don't" is probably only possible if the question was "Don't I?" or the same asked with intonation: "I don't?".

Comment: To follow up on this, I would say that “I don’t?” is probably the most commonly seen and used response, as it conveys a feeling of “really?”